How to handle unicode in postgresql query in Laravel
I have a table in my application that shows the jobs in queue. I want it to be possible to order the jobs by the uuid that is found within the payload of the Laravel jobs table. The problem is with the unicodes \u0000 present in the payload, which give me this error when I try to orderBy:
SQLSTATE\[42601\]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: invalid Unicode escape value at or near "'\\u0000" LINE 1: ...rom "jobs" order by regexp_replace(payload::text, '\\u0000', ... ^ (SQL: select \* from "jobs" order by regexp_replace(payload::text, '\\u0000', '', 'g')::json-\>\>'uuid' asc limit 10 offset 0)

I tried removing the unicodes in my controller logic this way:
$query = Job::query();

$sortField = $request->input('sortField', 'id');
$sortOrder = $request->input('sortOrder', 'asc');

if (!in_array($sortField, ['id', 'UUID', 'class', 'created_at', 'available_at', 'reserved_at', 'attempts', 'queue'])) {
    $sortField = 'id';
}

if ($sortField === 'UUID') {
    $query->orderByRaw("regexp_replace(payload::text, '\\u0000', '', 'g')::json->>'uuid' " . ($sortOrder == '1' ? 'asc' : 'desc'));
} elseif ($sortField === 'class') {
    $query->orderByRaw("regexp_replace(payload::text, '\\u0000', '', 'g')::json->>'displayName' " . ($sortOrder == '1' ? 'asc' : 'desc'));
} else {
    $query->orderBy($sortField, $sortOrder === '1' ? 'asc' : 'desc');
}

$data = $query->paginate(
    (int)$request->get("perPage", 10)
);

return new DBJsonResponse($data);

I tried other methods for replacing the unicodes, but none worked. How can I resolve this?

What language is this?  PHP?  How did you get nulls in these text fields to begin with?

If you are using PHP 7.0, you can write "\u{0000}".

You cannot have a NUL character in PostgreSQL, so you have to replace it in PHP.
